# How I can split HTML table after 'x' number of columns?

Tags: html, css, html-table

I'm trying to get a table row to split in half and stack after so many columns, but how can I do this with CSS?

I have tried to target the 12th column using td:nth-child(12), and a number of css attempts.

```css
td:nth-child(12) { white-space: nowrap; }
```

```html
<table>
    <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>7</td>
    <td>8</td>
    <td>9</td>
    <td>10</td>
    <td>11</td>
    <td>12</td>
    <td>13</td>
    <td>14</td>
    <td>15</td>
    <td>16</td>
    <td>17</td>
    <td>18</td>
    <td>19</td>
    <td>20</td>
    <td>21</td>
    <td>22</td>
    <td>23</td>
    <td>24</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I expect to be able to target the 12th column, then put the columns 13-24 on a row with CSS only. Or at least so 13-24 behave like a new row.

Comment: Well, it would be better to use more `<tr>`s, but you can also use `table tr { display: grid; grid-template-columns: repeat(12, 1fr)}`

Comment: after answered i show your comment, glad you answer in comment section

Comment: surely if your table columns need to wrap like that, then the table is not really displaying tabular data (as it wouldn't make sense due to the column headings not matching up) therefore you shouldn't be really using tables?

Comment: @elveti - Acknowledge you for been the first to anwser and appreciate your help :)

Comment: @Pete - It's in a dynamic environment and we can't touch the core HTML, banged my head so much to try gain access to the apllications src code - I just get told it's not my remit by project owner - ok then :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you could simply use flex-box.

```
tr {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

td {
    flex: calc(100% / 13);
}
```

This would also work with even more columns/tds.
I've made a simply Code-Pen for you :)

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/yWYzdr

Answer (score 4):

You can do like that, using `CSS grid`

```css
table tr {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(12, 1fr);
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>7</td>
    <td>8</td>
    <td>9</td>
    <td>10</td>
    <td>11</td>
    <td>12</td>
    <td>13</td>
    <td>14</td>
    <td>15</td>
    <td>16</td>
    <td>17</td>
    <td>18</td>
    <td>19</td>
    <td>20</td>
    <td>21</td>
    <td>22</td>
    <td>23</td>
    <td>24</td>
    <td>25</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: This worked for me also @Nisharg, wish stackoverflow would allow me to have 2 accepted anwsers :)

Comment: Above answer have some glitch because its substrate value from `100%` and result is in **point** so from my side it's not acceptable answer but glad you like my answer also, Thanks !!